# How to create mongodb collection without _id

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb, gmongo

My project was build on GMONGO framework and all the domains were created with attribute id as a string.So grail frame work will create mongodb collections with _id attribute when application is app.
       In UI there was a limitation to retrive _id.So in service "_id" is rewrite to "id" to overcome the issue.
     Could we created collections with "id" by default rather than "_id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant. Mongo will automaticaly create _id if you dont specify any.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/glossary/

In your case you can add `index` to `id` field, and when run queries just add projection to exclude _id.

So you will have something like this in data

`{_id: mongoDbID, id: yourId, ...}`

And run query like this

`collection.find({id: yourId}).project({_id: 0}).toArray();`

You will get this as an result

`{id: yourId, ...}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: _id will be create if you are not define id in domain,but i am defining id attribute in my domain even though mongo is creating _id rather than id. My requirement is get a gson objecct with key is id not _id

Comment: Is there any way to create id rather than _id?

Comment: I answer that you cant. This is how mongo works. You can choose another DB, or just dont care about _id in system. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in mongoDB v3.4，you can create a collection without _id index.

Use the following statement:

```
db.createCollection("myCollection", { autoIndexId: false })
```